# How to include multiple content blocks in a layout template created by a standalone Meteor package

Tags: javascript, templates, meteor, namespaces, package

I want to create a Meteor package that provides a template for a grid layout where the user can resize and reorder the grid blocks by dragging them.  This template provides the layout, but I want to be able to pass in arbitrary templates to get embedded inside the grid blocks.

I don't want the package providing the layout template to depend on any other packages or have any a priori knowledge or references to the content templates.

At first I was thinking I could use `Template.dynamic` and pass the template name to use for each grid block in the data for the layout template, but then I realized probably the layout template will say "template not found" because it probably can't access any templates outside of its package or dependencies (and of course I don't want it to depend on anything else).

`UI.contentBlock` is almost what I'm looking for, but the problem is that you can only pass one block of content into the template -- and I want to be able to pass in an arbitrary number of content blocks.

Now I'm thinking what I'll have to do is pass in the JS template objects as data for the layout template, and install them with `Blaze.render()` or something like that in the layout template's `onRendered()` hook.  But that seems potentially fragile to me and I'd rather sacrifice code reuse and just define the layout template in my app namespace so it can access all content templates the app can access.

Does anyone have any other ideas how to solve this?

This is an exploratory question as I haven't actually started using Meteor yet -- I'm trying to identify what would be difficult in Meteor if I switch to it from React.

Comment: Why don't you edit or start a new question for what you are really looking for

Comment: okay, I've edited it.  Sorry for the thrash